# Square Python API "unexpected keyword argument" TypeError despite being expected

Tags: python, square

I'm trying to use Square's Python API to GET some data using the [example code they provide in their GitHub repo](https://github.com/square/square-python-sdk#usage):

```
from square.client import Client
 
# Create an instance of the API Client 
# and initialize it with the credentials 
# for the Square account whose assets you want to manage
 
client = Client( access_token='{ACCESS_TOKEN}',
    environment='production'
)
 
# Get an instance of the Square API you want call
api_locations = client.locations
```

Running this gives the following error (last few lines only):

```
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/square/http/requests_client.py", line 67, in create_default_http_cient
    retries = Retry(total=max_retries, backoff_factor=backoff_factor,
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allowed_methods'
```

Which confuses me because my understanding is that this instantiates a `urllib3` `Retry` object which [according to the liburl3 GitHub repo](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/blob/main/src/urllib3/util/retry.py#L200)  does seem to have an `allowed_methods` keyword argument.

I've already checked the `squareup` package requirements.